# Subscription Expiration Date

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

I have a question regarding the receipt format for In App Purchases.

The main receipt object has a field called `Subscription Expiration Date`.

But what if an app has multiple types of renewing subscriptions, what will this field reflect then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `Subscription Expiration Date` in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1), however if you read below the actual name of the json key is `expires_date`, just wanted to point that out before you go on a search hunt not finding it in your app.

To answer your question, you will see that on the documentation, that specific key `Subscription Expiration Date` is listed under a heading called `In-App Purchase Receipt Fields`. That means, and I can confirm from my own experience, that this key is present for every In-App purchase of a subscription individually and every renewal thereon forth. That means there can be multiple purchases, each as their own entry into the receipt-json, with each having a `expires_date`.

If you want to use that key for validation, the receipt will have a request date sent from the apple server. Use that date to see if one of those subscriptions is still running.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Here's an example of an actual parsed receipt for orientation.
Note That I have removed some ids for safety. Here you see a receipt where at the top you see receipt specific information, followed by a one time purchase and then a yearly subscription that was renewed about 4 times.

```
["original_purchase_date_pst": Optional(2013-08-01 00:00:00 
America/Los_Angeles), 
"bundle_id": Optional(yourAppBundleId), 
"receipt_creation_date_pst": Optional(2018-12-20 02:20:38 America/Los_Angeles), 
"receipt_type": Optional(ProductionSandbox), 
"app_item_id": Optional(0), "application_version": Optional(2), 
"request_date_pst": Optional(2018-12-20 02:20:41 America/Los_Angeles), 
"original_purchase_date_ms": Optional(1375340400000), 
"receipt_creation_date_ms": Optional(1545301238000), 
"in_app": Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x283b736b0>(

{
    "is_trial_period" = false;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2018-12-07 12:00:43 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1544184043000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 04:00:43 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = XXXXXXXXXXXXX;
    "product_id" = "someSinglePurchase";
    "purchase_date" = "2018-12-07 12:00:43 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1544184043000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 04:00:43 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
},
{
    "expires_date" = "2018-12-07 13:01:21 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_ms" = 1544187681000;
    "expires_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 05:01:21 America/Los_Angeles";
    "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
    "is_trial_period" = false;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2018-12-07 12:01:22 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1544184082000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 04:01:22 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
    "product_id" = "yearlySubscription";
    "purchase_date" = "2018-12-07 12:01:21 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1544184081000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 04:01:21 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
},
{
    "expires_date" = "2018-12-07 14:01:35 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_ms" = 1544191295000;
    "expires_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 06:01:35 America/Los_Angeles";
    "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
    "is_trial_period" = false;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2018-12-07 12:01:22 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1544184082000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 04:01:22 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
    "product_id" = "yearlySubscription";
    "purchase_date" = "2018-12-07 13:01:35 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1544187695000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 05:01:35 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
},
{
    "expires_date" = "2018-12-07 15:01:35 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_ms" = 1544194895000;
    "expires_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 07:01:35 America/Los_Angeles";
    "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
    "is_trial_period" = false;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2018-12-07 12:01:22 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1544184082000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 04:01:22 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
    "product_id" = "yearlySubscription";
    "purchase_date" = "2018-12-07 14:01:35 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1544191295000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2018-12-07 06:01:35 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 10000XXXXXXXXX;
}
```